# Matlab Recursion Not Working as Intended

Tags: arrays, matlab, recursion

So I'm trying to write some pretty basic code to essentially create an array of random numbers, based on certain rules.  My end goal is to try to have an array of numbers, in which none of them match one another.  However, it seems like the end array that my code is outputting has numbers that match, and I can't seem to figure out why.

I've pasted a sample output below, and as you can see, some of the numbers in the 'Totals' array match.  I'm guessing something is wrong with the way I wrote the recursive 'addboard' function, but I have no clue what's wrong.  If anyone could provide some advice, that'd be great.  Thanks.

```
function [Components,Totals] = BoardForm1()
BoardLengths = [4,6,8,10,12];
Initial = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
Components = zeros(8,14);
Totals = zeros(8,14);

for i=1:14
    for row = 1:length(Initial)
          [currentboard,test] = addboard(row,BoardLengths,Initial,Totals);
          Initial(row) = test;
          Components(row,i) = currentboard
          Totals(row,i) = test
    end
end
end


function [currentboard,test] = addboard(x,BoardLengths,Initial,Totals)
currentboard = BoardLengths(randi(length(BoardLengths)));
test = Initial(x) + currentboard;
if ismember(test,Totals)
    addboard(x,BoardLengths,Initial,Totals);
end
end

Totals =

12    16    28    34    44    56    68    76    84    94   106   114   118   128
13    25    35    39    43    49    53    61    65    75    83    91    95   103
 6    18    22    34    42    50    54    66    72    82    86    92   104   112
15    23    35    41    51    57    63    69    73    81    87    99   105   111
14    26    36    48    58    68    80    90   100   104   108   114   120   130
 9    13    23    27    31    37    43    49    55    61    65    75    87    91
12    24    34    42    46    54    60    64    72    76    82    88    92    96
19    29    33    39    47    57    69    77    83    89   101   109   119   125
```

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB passes by value, so any changes made in the recursed addboard is ignored since its output values are ignored. Fix by setting the output values of [currentboard, test] = addboard

In general, I recommend doing this iteratively (while loop) instead of recursively. There may even be a one-liner that can do this, but I'm not sure from the comments what the requirements of the board are.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to understand your code, maybe some comments what the functions are supposed to do would be helpful, but just on a formal level reading the code there is at least one error in these lines:

```
if ismember(test,Totals)
    addboard(x,BoardLengths,Initial,Totals);
end
```

You are calling `addboard` without output arguments which has no effect. It should probably be:

```
if ismember(test,Totals)
    [currentboard,test] = addboard(x,BoardLengths,Initial,Totals);
end
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - looks like it worked!  Unfortunately it now looks like it's hitting a recursion limit of 500.

Comment: It seems your algorithm get´s stuck with an impossible choice because all options are already present in Totals, but from your code I am unable to understand what kind of distribution you are trying to implement.